# Добавить карту при добавление записи. Вордпрес

Tags: wordpress, карты

Когда пользователь добавляет запись, то внизу должна быть карта, и стоять маркер где он приблизительно находится. Как это реализовать? __ Копался в исходниках все разбросано

Comment: Не надо никаких исходников. Тем более, что функционала карт ядро не имеет. Есть куча плагинов для вывода карт.

Comment: Попробуйте что-то из этого: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/#plugins (там внизу плагины для Wordpress)